# Using pandas, how do I get the data in the first set of columns before it runs into an empty field which is then followed up later with more data?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to clean up an excel file so that I can import the data with [Timestamp, ID, Energy Value] and not [Year, error, kW] into a database. Both sets of data are separated by a large gap because originally the second set of data was used for analysis. In excel, you can start from the bottom of the sheet and go up until you hit the first line with data and then again when you hit a blank space to keep track of which chunk you're dealing with. Is there a way to achieve the same with pandas? I know that you can set a specific range but if the size varies how would I set it so that range doesn't matter.

[This is an example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReZHW.png) but the space in between the two chunks of data is much larger and the data size in general is also very large.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can first find the indices where the values are null. Once you have the indices, you can use that to split the total dataframe into 2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,np.NaN, np.NaN, 5 ,6], 'b':[1,2,3,4,np.NaN,np.NaN, 5,6]})

#indices of missing values
missingList = df.index[pd.isna(df.a)].tolist()

#Subsetting from beginning to occurence of first NaN
df1 = df.iloc[:missingList[0]]

#Subsetting from last NaN till the end
df2 = df.iloc[missingList[-1]+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Update 1/9/18:
>
> I took a different approach. I used usecols to grab the columns that I
>   needed. I did the following to grab the specific columns I needed:

```
df = pd.read_csv('worksheet.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']], skiprows=[1], usecols=dictionary[n])
```

>
and then I used the following to get rid of the gap as well as the information after said gap:
>

```
    first_nan = df[df.Date_Time == 'nan nan'].first_valid_index()
    df = df[:first_nan]
```

> The second code block searches for the first instance of a "nan nan" value (null/blank value) and rewrites the dataframe with all the information up to that specific value.